# How to print Unicode like "\u{variable}"?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

For example, i can print Unicode symbol like:

```
println("\u{00A3}" )  // print "£"
```

if i want to print with Unicode range like "00A1 to 00A7"

how can i use for loop to print?

```
for var code = 0x00A1; code < 0x00A8; ++code { 
    println("\u{code}")
}
```

this can't work

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
for var code = 0x00A1; code < 0x00A8; code++
{
    var t:UnicodeScalar = UnicodeScalar(code)
    println("\(t)")
}
```

Prints:

¡

¢

£

¤

¥

¦

§